# 2 or more forms directing to a single XML file

Tags: java, servlets, deployment-descriptor

I have created a web page in which I have 4 separate form and obviously each of them have different action value.

eg:

```
<form action="web1">
</form>

<form action="web2">
</form>

<form action="web3">
</form>

<form action="web4">
</form>
```

Now I have 4 individual servlet files for each form. But how do I give path in xml file? XML file accepting only 1 web-app tag and only 1 pair of servlet and servlet-mapping

eg:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>web1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>ShortServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>web1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/web1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here ShortServlet is the name of the servlet of form web1

What should I write in XML so that it accesses all 4 forms?

Answer (score 2):

> 2 or more forms directing to a single XML file

This XML file is special; is called *deployment descriptor* and has a very specific name **web.xml**. It's highly incorrect to reference it as just another XML data file in your question.

> XML file accepting only 1 web-app tag and only 1 pair of servlet and servlet-mapping

This is inaccurate as well. You can have mutiple `<servlet-mapping>` tags inside the `<web-app>` tag. The reason you can't have more than one `<web-app>` tag is because the deployment descriptor describes mappings for a single web application only.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple Instead of using input type as `submit`  in  `Html` form use `button` and call javascript functions and redirect to  respective servlet. and no need to declare any thing in `web.xml` file.